# Facebook Audience Network Quality Check always FAILS

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

My app always fails quality check for FAN. I followed all best practices which show on below links.

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/best-practices
2. https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/2232135336814226
3. https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/1216784088497802?helpref=inprod

I tried updating my app with different placements but non of those are working, One day my app is passing in quality check and the other day its failing. Again after updating with new placements, its passing and after 2-3 days it gets fail again.

I don't know what is happening with FAN. Can anyone tell me how to solve this quality check issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of app you have? Are you loading the ad at the same time with the content? If you load the content first and then the ad load and move the content this cause the quality check fails.

Comment: @Quimbo I have integrated FAN ads in one app which is of tools category app. My app can be used in daily life everyday. After reading you comment I have check my current ads integration and I realize that Though I am loading ads at the same time when I load my app content, Ads loading time will depend on users internet connection. And because of that when ads taking time to load my apps content shifts a little. I have solved that problem as you said, Hope this helps. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: @MayurGadhiya did you manage to solve your issue? I am facing the issue with my utility app as well.

Comment: @venkat Unfortunately not, I tried so hard to pass in quality check but no luck at all. Only Facebook can help us with this now but all they do is provide us above mentioned links. My app still fails the quality check.

Answer (score 0):

Check any unusual activity in your app, monitor the statistics, are you getting any unusual revenue or click-through rates for ad placement. If yes, try a different implementation technique or a different ad space. Do not click your own ad.